# The Style parameter in timezones

Tags: java, parameters, timezone

Java `Timezone` class have the following method:

> public final String getDisplayName(boolean daylight, int style)

What values can `style` have and how does it affect the result? Is there an enumeration for the values?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? It seems pretty clear here.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I didn't understand it right from the documentation. Now with the answers I got it

Comment: I don't understand why you would ask "what values can `style` have" when the documentation states: "either LONG or SHORT" with each value being a link to a constant. I'm genuinely interested in how the documentation could have been written more clearly here.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I didn't understand that these values are under Timezone.

Comment: Did you try following the links though? That makes it pretty clear, IMO. Admittedly the parameter documentation could have been more explicit about their usage... something like "The style of display name to obtain" but I think the rest is pretty good. I'm only asking as I want to write my own documentation in a way that makes this sort of question unnecessary.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, the link from the second documentation suggested value "1", which I had figured out by myself. But I still didn't know where the values are defined.

Comment: Hmm... maybe we're viewing a different version of the documentation. When you click through in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html, you stay on the `TimeZone` page, so it's declared in `TimeZone`. Never mind, anyway - thanks for the extra info.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, here is the documentation link I looked at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html

Comment: Ah... those docs don't have it linked, which makes it harder to tell. The v7 docs are definitely better.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thanks, I'll remember to check newer versions of documentation next time )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

> Timezone.SHORT
>
> A style specifier for getDisplayName() indicating a short name, such as "PST."

> Timezone.LONG
>
> A style specifier for getDisplayName() indicating a long name, such as "Pacific Standard Time."